# How can I prevent memory overwrite when managing types of different sizes in the same buffer?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Currently, I have a polymorphic container that can store any type in an inheritance hierarchy. To do so, I manage my own buffer.

I want to support any future type that can be added, so I don't want to set a static size for the types that can be added to the container.

In my buffer, since a smaller type might be stored before a larger type, there was an overwrite that occurred when I had to remove the smaller element and then shift the larger one.

**Note:** For the following example, all types in the buffer inherit from the same base class.

Consider this memory layout containing a one byte object **A** (byte 0) followed by a 2 byte object **B** (bytes 2 and 3):

```
// initial state
[ a ][ b ][ b ]

// remove a
[ x ][ b ][ b ]

// x is the position to shift to, capital B is the overwritten byte
[ b ][ B ][   ]
```

I want to erase **A**, so I destroy the associated object (which means that `a` is now available to me), and then I want to move construct **B** starting at `a`. Clearly there will be an overwrite when I attempt to write byte 1, since byte 1 is already occupied by **B** itself.

---

I attempted to fix this issue during the allocation phase, by keeping track of the size of the previous element allocated, I could reserve enough padding bytes to prevent this. With this new strategy, the memory layout would look like this:

```
// initial state, when I added B, padding bytes = sizeof( B ) - sizeof( last ) = 1
[ a ][ - ][ b ][ b ]

// remove a, we can clearly see that there's enough space for B now
[ x ][ - ][ b ][ b ]

// safe to move B to position x
[ b ][ b ][   ][   ]
```

I only add padding bytes if the object being added is larger than the previous one.

---

However, even after that fix, erasing elements can still cause the issue to occur:

```
// initial state: object a is 1 byte, object b is 1 byte, object c is 4 bytes
[ a ][ - ][ - ][ c ][ c ][ c ][ b ][ - ][ - ][ c ][ c ][ c ]

// erase first c, occupying bytes 1 through 5
[ a ][ b ][ - ][ - ][ c ][ c ][ c ][   ][   ][   ][   ][   ]

// erase b
[ a ][ x ][ - ][ - ][ c ][ c ][ c ][   ][   ][   ][   ][   ]

// shift c - since c > a, required padding = c - a = 4 - 1 = 3
[ a ][ - ][ - ][ - ][ x ][ c ][ c ][ c ][   ][   ][   ][   ]

// when attempting to shift C, there will be an overwrite at the capital C bytes
[ a ][ - ][ - ][ - ][ c ][ C ][ C ][   ][   ][   ][   ][   ]
```

---

Here is a simple program that produces the overwriting issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <cstdint>

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

struct A : public virtual Base /* 16 byte */
{
    A( char x ) : x_{ x } {}
    virtual void print() const { std::cout << x_ << '\n'; }
    char x_;
};

struct B : public virtual Base /* 24 bytes */
{
    B( long double x ) : x_{ x } {}
    virtual void print() const{ std::cout << x_ << '\n'; }
    long double x_;
};

int main()
{
    unsigned char data[ sizeof( A ) + sizeof( B ) ];

    // these are stored as void*, used polymorphically in the actual code
    A* pa = ::new ( &data ) A{ 1 };
    B* pb = ::new ( &data + sizeof( A ) ) B{ 2 };

    pa->print();
    pb->print();

    // I want to remove the first A from my list
    pa->~A();

    // shift following element back, overwrite due to its larger size
    pb = ::new ( &data ) B{ *pb };
}
```

---

Possible solutions I've considered:

- Keep track of the largest element added, always use enough padding to ensure that overwrites can't happen. This will waste a lot of memory if a really large object is added, and many small objects then follow.
- Suggested by [@ratchetfreak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/731620/ratchet-freak): Do not move anything, simply create a new buffer and move it all there once the unused memory becomes large enough.
- Create a temporary buffer when I detect an overwrite will occur, transfer everything there, then back to my normal buffer. (Perhaps I can decide whether it is better to move into this new buffer, or move the conflicting elements back.)

Comment: You say, "I have a polymorphic container," but I don't see any actual polymorphism in your code.  Make an actual polymorphic base class, and use a container such as std::vector to store pointers (ideally smart pointers) to the base class, then you don't have to worry about the memory.

Comment: If you store pointers, you won't have to deal with these. Pointers have the same sizr no matter what they point to.

Comment: @DanKorn It's hard to post a MVCE, because the actual problem has a lot more associated code, but I posted the basic issue, which doesn't require the actual code. Read this to see what I am implementing: https://github.com/user2296177/polymorphic-container/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @IvanRubinson The whole point of my polymorphic container is to not use pointers, I want the class to own the objects. Check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: what you are thinking about is a union: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b.aspx

Comment: Okay, well, unlike the code you posted, the article you link to does use polymorphism.  But I would still solve the problem the article poses with a vector of smart pointers.  Or at least I would solve its first "issue," that the vector doesn't manage the objects' lifetimes, that way.  Its second "issue," that the objects are not stored contiguously in memory, doesn't really seem like a problem to me.

Comment: 1) union is not the solution here 2) "use a smart pointer" is not the solution to "how do I store multiple types in the same contiguous buffer, instead of a contiguous buffer of pointers to multiple types"

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem, but can't you just use `memcpy` to move the object? I think that `memcpy` takes into consideration the case of overlapping source and target buffers.